# How do I change all of the "/" to ")" in all of lines of a file that end in ")"

Tags: linux, vim

I am using vim and I think I know how to change all of the / to ) but I do not know how to apply it for only lines that end in )

I want to change this:

```
apples/oranges/grapes) 
apples/oranges/grapes 
apples/oranges/grapes)      
apples/oranges/grapes
```

to this:

```
apples)oranges)grapes)
apples/oranges/grapes
apples)oranges)grapes)
apples/oranges/grapes
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. In such cases you should always provide example input and the desired output.

Comment: Does this make more sense? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Are there empty lines in between or is that just a formatting problem?

Comment: Formatting problem.

Comment: There should be no empty lines

Comment: Have you met our friend sed? Would you be opposed to piping the vim contents %! to sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vim` solution is very similar to the `sed` solution:

```
:g/)$/s!/!)!gEnter
```

I’m assuming that you want to edit only the lines
where the last character is `)`. 
If you want to include lines where `)` is the last *non-blank* character,
use

```
:g/)\s*$/s!/!)!gEnter
```

where `\s` is code for a **s**pace character (space or tab). 
I'm using `!` the way [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402187/80216#402190) uses `+`;
that’s just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I have not used sed before so this makes a little more sense. But why :g instead of :%s

Comment: `:%s` does a substitution on every line.  You need to use `:g` to select *some* of the lines in the buffer, and do something to them and only them.  (For example, ``:g/banana/d`` will *delete* all lines that contain “`banana`”.)

Comment: ahhh okay that makes sense. This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/) *$/s+/+)+g' input
```

The `/) *$/` part selects the lines to be changed. The `*` is related to the fact that there are spaces after the `)`. But maybe these spaces are not intentional.